# graphql and serverless offline running in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, serverless-framework

I have this docker file:

```
FROM node:6-slim
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python2.7 make g++ git bzip2 libfreetype6 libfontconfig1 \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
  && ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python

RUN cd $(npm root -g)/npm \
  && npm install serverless -g\
  && npm install fs-extra \
  && sed -i -e s/graceful-fs/fs-extra/ -e s/fs\.move/fs.rename/ ./lib/utils/rename.js

ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
CMD [REV=$(git rev-list -n 1 HEAD 'package.json');]
CMD [STAMP=$(git show --pretty=format:%ai --abbrev-commit "$REV" | head -n 1);]
CMD [touch -d "$STAMP" package.json;]

RUN cd /tmp && npm install --quiet --production \
  && npm rebuild bcrypt \
  && rm -Rf node_modules/ffprobe-static/bin/darwin \
  && rm -Rf node_modules/ffprobe-static/bin/win32

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD . /usr/src/app
RUN cd /usr/src/app \
  && git gc --aggressive --prune=all

ENV PORT 9999

EXPOSE 9999
CMD [ "npm", "run", "offline" ]
```

When I run it, all works without problems, but when I try to access the docker instance:

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' serverless
172.17.0.3
```

When I go to `172.17.0.3:9999` I am not able to connect to the instance.

Whereas if I run my application from my local machine, `localhost:9999` responds.

Here is a copy of my serverless.yml:

```
service: serverless-graphql

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs4.3
  timeout: 30
  stage: dev
# you can add statements to the Lambda function's IAM Role here
  iamRoleStatements:
       -  Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - dynamodb:*
          Resource: "*"
       -  Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - s3:*
          Resource: "*"
# you can define service wide environment variables here
  environment:
    database: mongo
    MONGO_URI: "mongodb://docker-mongo:27017/test-db"

functions:
  graphql:
    handler: lib/handler.graphql
    timeout: 12
    events:
      - http:
          path: graphql
          method: post
          cors: true

  stripewebhook:
    handler: lib/handler.stripewebhook
    events:
      - http:
          path: stripewebhook
          method: post
          cors: true
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your nodejs app listens on `0.0.0.0` and not `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: thanks, that was it

Comment: @NehalJWani can you explain why access by localhost will not work?

Comment: @DavidHe Because by listening on `localhost`, your application binds itself to the Loopback interface, which is not accessible to services outside that network namespace. One can read more about it at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost#Loopback

Comment: @NehalJWani hey thanks for your reply. But the services is actually listening on some specific IP right? Is that possible to know what that ip is and hit that ip from outside the container?

Comment: When you listen on `localhost`, the specific IP address your application listens on is actually `127.0.0.1`, which is a special IP address, again specific to that network namespace. Which is why you need to listen on all interfaces, or on the particular IP address of that container, so that things outside that network namespace can access it.